# From child to parent route, Ember transitions to parent.index subroute

Tags: ember.js

I'm linking from a child route to a parent route.

In this example, I'm linking from a 'category' child page to the parent 'availability' page.

I understand that the Ember Router skips the model hook on links/transitions to a parent route.
I'm just looking for the beforeModel hook to be called on the parent route.

It does this all well and good, but it goes to the **availability.index subroute**, which is not where my beforeModel hook is written (see console output). My beforeModel hook is written in the **availability** route.

I could duplicate or move code to the index subroute, but I really don't understand why Ember is doing this. Putting my hooks in the **availability** route works all the time except for this case.

**Here's my router pattern:**

```
this.resource('availability', function() {
  this.resource('category', {path: '/category/:category'});
})
```

**Category Template**

```
{{#link-to 'availability'}}
  <span>Go Back</span> 
{{/link-to}}
```

**Console transition output:**

```
Attempting transition to availability
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transition #5: availability.index: calling beforeModel hook
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transition #5: availability.index: calling deserialize hook   
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transition #5: availability.index: calling afterModel hook  
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transition #5: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition.    
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transitioned into 'availability.index'   
ember.js?body=1:15374 Transition #5: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

Comment: Because your `category` route is nested under `availability`, the model of `availability` does not need to be resolved again.  
`beforeModel` hook is called only when the route is being transitioned to with a fresh model, or from another route which is not nested under it.
What exactly are you doing in the `beforeModel` hook? (Maybe you need to move this code to another hook)

Comment: What happens if I have things like redirects? Let's say availability redirects to the first category.  From there, there's a global nav and the user clicks 'availability' for some reason (it happens).  Ember will go to availability.index and not run the redirect the first category, creating a jarring experience.

Comment: `redirect` is called within the `afterModel` hook, meaning the model for `availability` has already been resolved.  There's an old saying in Emberish, "if it's too complicated you are doing it wrong". Can you elaborate about the logic you execute in the `beforeModel` hook?